# Drop down to populate second drop down

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

So I'm at a little bit of a loss on this one, I have a data validation box that loads a list from another sheet, the formula goes something like:

```
='Data Validation'!$B$2:$B$8
```

That is working without issue, however I have a second drop down that I can't figure out, the easiest way to explain it is like this

```
| Data Validation 1|
  |Option 1 > Loads Options in column C of Data Validation for Data Validation cell 2|
  |Option 2 > Loads Options in column D of Data Validation for Data Validation cell 2|
  |Option 3 > Loads Options in column E of Data Validation for Data Validation cell 2|
  |Option 4 > Loads Options in column F of Data Validation for Data Validation cell 2|
  |Option 5 > Loads Options in column G of Data Validation for Data Validation cell 2|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the items in your first dropdown, create **Named Ranges** for each of the items on your list with exactly the same name as your first list

Example: If your list has "Ford","Honda","Toyota","GM" then you would create named ranges called Ford, Honda, Toyota and GM that have the responses for the 2nd dropdown

[image: Example]
(Note they don't have to be the same size)

Then, you can make the source for your dropdown `=INDIRECT(A1)`

If you have spaces in your list, then use an underscore in the named range (e.g. *Rolls Royce* would become **Rolls_Royce** as the range name, and the formula would become:
`=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","_"))`

Comment: So in my case I have "Item" In cell G3, I want cell E3 to load the values that tie to G3 > DataValidation!"Watches" or some other named range, how would that work?   I'm not having too much luck yet.